# yii 'through' relation search

Tags: yii

I have the following tables.

```
User:
---------
id<br>
firstName

Project:
---------
id<br>
Name

StaffingManager
---------------
id<br>
User_id(FK)<br>
Total_Staff<br>

StaffingProjectMonth
-----------------------
id<br>
Project_id(FK)<br>
StaffingManager_id(FK)<br>
```

I want to define the relations in StaffingProjectMonth model

*This is the default relation defined by YII using gii*

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'project' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Project', 'Project_id'),
            'staffingManager' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'StaffingManager', 'StaffingManager_id'),
        );
    }
```

I was able to get the ProjectName and search by ProjectName.

I want to get the UserfirstName and search by that.

I defined the relation this way.

```
return array(
            'project' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Project', 'Project_id'),

            'staffingmanager' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'StaffingManager', 'StaffingManager_id'),

            'user'=> array(self::HAS_MANY,'User',array('User_id'=>'id'),'through'=>'staffingmanager' ),
        );
```

and in search method I did this:

```
$criteria->with = array('project','user');
//$criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
$criteria->compare('Name',$this->Project_id,true);
$criteria->compare('firstName',$this->StaffingManager_id,true);
```

and in the view:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'staffing-project-month-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(       
    //  'id',       
        array('name'=>'Project_id','header'=>'Project','value'=>'$data->project->Name',),
        array('name'=>'StaffingManager_id','header'=>'User','value'=>'$data->staffingmanager->user->firstName',),
        ..............
```

only the search by project name works. Able to sess the UserfirstName but unable to search by the firstName. Some wrong in defining relations.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the following [excellent wiki article by redguy](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview/), that describes how to search by related model attributes:

Following the approach of this article:

You should declare two new variables in your model:

```
public $project_name;
public $staffingmanager_firstname;
```

You should declare these new variables as safe for search in the `rules()` method:

```
array( 'project_name,staffingmanager_firstname,...', 'safe', 'on'=>'search' ),
```

Your `search()` method criteria should look like this:

```
$criteria->compare('project.Name',$this->project_name,true);
$criteria->compare('user.firstName',$this->staffingmanager_firstname,true);
```

In your view file, the 'columns' should be:

```
array('name'=>'project_name','header'=>'Project','value'=>'$data->project->Name',),     
array('name'=>'staffingmanager_firstname','header'=>'User','value'=>'$data->user->firstName',),
```

Hope this helps.

Best regards...

Answer (score 0):

I had troubles with $criteria->with and ”through“ relation. 
Thing was in relation kind. BELONGS_TO doesn't work correct. I switched it to HAS_ONE and inverted id direction — array('parent_id'=>'id'). Now it's working!